# Get Kind of Asset Field

Tags: assets

I have an entry with one asset field and i need to determine if the 'kind' of asset is either 'json' file or 'video' file. Basically I swap my HTML based on the return 'kind'.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Craft CMS beginner.

```
{% set videoEntries =  craft.entries({ section: 'mediaRoomVideos' }).find %}
{% if videoEntries is not empty %}

    {% for entry in videoEntries %}
        {% set asset = entry.mediaVideo.first() %}

        {% if asset %}

            {% set json = asset.kind('json') %}
                {% if json %}
                    Do Embedded Video
                {% else %}

                    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="{{ entry.mediaVideo.first.getUrl() }}">
                    </video>

                {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{% if json %}
```

Replaced with.

```
{% if asset.kind == 'json' %}
```